# SQL Left Outer join with where clause reduces results from left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that works exactly how I would expect it to. It returns back all of the Statuses with the counts.

```
SELECT 
    ProcessStatuses.Status, 
    COUNT(SecretProcesses.ProcessStatusID) AS Count
FROM  
    ProcessStatuses
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    SecretProcesses ON ProcessStatuses.ProcessStatusID = SecretProcesses.ProcessStatusID
GROUP BY 
    ProcessStatuses.Status
```

Result:

```
Status  Count
-------------
status1 0
status2 0
status3 0
status4 0
status5 0
status6 1
status7 0
status8 0
```

However if I add a `WHERE` clause to the query it returns back only the statuses that have counts.

For example

```
SELECT 
    ProcessStatuses.Status, 
    COUNT(SecretProcesses.ProcessStatusID) AS Count
FROM 
    ProcessStatuses
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    SecretProcesses ON ProcessStatuses.ProcessStatusID = SecretProcesses.ProcessStatusID
WHERE 
    AreaID IN (21, 22, 23)
GROUP BY 
    ProcessStatuses.Status
```

Result:

```
Status  Count
---------------
status6 1
```

This kind of defeats the purpose of doing a left outer join since I want to be able to filter the results by area that they reside in, while still displaying all of the possible statuses. The where clause is only returning statuses that have values, rather than all of them.

Comment: What happens if you use Count(1) or instead of Count(SecretProcesses.ProcessStatusId).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you still want to return all the statuses and `AreaId` is in the `SecretProcesses` table, you need to move the `where` criteria to the `on` condition because it is negating your `outer join`:

```
SELECT PS.Status, COUNT(SPProcessStatusID) AS Count
FROM ProcessStatuses PS
    LEFT JOIN SecretProcesses SP ON PS.ProcessStatusID = SP.ProcessStatusID 
        AND SP.AreaID IN (21, 22, 23)
GROUP BY PS.Status
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly and makes sense now that I'm looking at it more.